# Should we volunteer to test 1-reputation voting?

Tags: discussion, voting, reputation

### What is this about?

You may have noticed the Meta post in the sidebar: [If more users could vote, would they engage more? Testing 1 reputation voting on some sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/393127/255554).

In brief, Stack Exchange is looking for sites to participate in a test, wherein:

- Everybody can vote, i.e., the reputation required for both up- and downvoting would be lowered to 1.
- There is no reputation cost for downvoting answers.
- Registering your account is still required for voting.

The desired effect is that this increases user engagement and recruiting.
The concerns are that this increases vote fraud and low-quality votes.

### This question

Should we volunteer to participate in this test?
Since this is a simple yes/no decision, **please indicate your agreement by voting on this question:** upvote for *yes;* downvote for *no.*

Post any arguments or concerns you might have as an answer. I will do so as well.

### A note to visitors

This question is about whether the proposed changes or participating in this test is beneficial **for this site**, not to SE in general or any other site. If you want to discuss the latter, please take it to [Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/393127/255554).

Answer (score 7):

I am for this because I think it’s likely beneficial for our particular site:

#### Why Graphic Design of all sites?

The proposed changes have their clear up- and downsides and which weigh more depends on the specific site. I expect that Graphics Design is strongly on the benefitting side (and by far amongst the sites I am familiar with), for the following reasons:

- We have a clear shortage of new, engaged users and lowering the entry is likely to recruit some.
- We are short on votes, which reduces the reward for engaged users, both new and old.
- We do not have controversial content. For example, people invading our site to support or quench some opinion expressed in an answer is unlikely to happen.
- By the nature of our topic, we get a lot of drive-by users who might want to upvote posts that were truly helpful but cannot due to the reputation threshold.
- We have a low incidence of vote fraud and similar issues that this change may exacerbate.

By contrast, I would argue Academia SE (another site I moderate) does not tick any of these boxes and implementing 1-rep voting would be a clearly bad idea.

#### Isn’t volunteering to be a guinea pig risky?

There is no denying that there is some risk involved since we are exploring unchartered waters here.
However, I do think that this risk is manageable and worth it.
In short, I statistically expect the outcome to be positive.

In particular, I am not for this because I think some site should test it or that it’s better us than some other site. I am for this because I think that participating in the test itself is a good choice for us, even if we take into account the risks.

Comment: If you mods want to deal with the extra support that it likely requires, I don't mind adding it

Comment: We have mostly a problem of having booring questions.